# I have multiplied 2 inputs to show in a 'Totals' box, but it doesn't multiply the other rows

Tags: javascript

```js
 function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qid').value;
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('uid').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('subsubtotal');
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
    }
```

```html
<tr>
    <td><form><input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="qid" data-quantity name="qamount"  min="0" data-validation="number" class="qinput txt" value="{{Quantity}}" /></form></td>
    <td><form><input type="text" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max100" class="dinput" value="{{Details}}" /></form></td>
    <td><form><input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="uid" data-unitprice name="uamount" min="0" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" class="uinput txt" value="{{UnitPrice}}" /></form></td>
    <td><form><input readonly id="subsubtotal" name="totalamount" class="sinput txt" value="{{Subtotal}}" /></form></td>  
</tr>
```

[This is what I mean by it only multiplies the top row and not the ones following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf9Xg.png)
So the code calculates the top rows, however the rows below (are added by clicking the button) and so on do not calculate.

Comment: There is no reason (or sense) in wrapping every input with a `form` element. You don't use the form submission anyway...

Comment: I know I haven't gotten rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default values from `<input>` will be a `string`. You would need to parse them before multiplying.

As **@Ronen Cypis** mentioned, I don't see any meaning in wrapping the contents in a `form`.

---

**Update:**

It's becuase of the `id` attribute. `id` should be unique in the whole document. So the input boxes in the next rows should have a different `id`. Check below example.

```js
function calculate(obj) {
  var tr = obj.parentNode.parentNode;

  var myBox1 = tr.cells[0].children[0].value;
  var myBox2 = tr.cells[2].children[0].value;
  var result = tr.cells[3].children[0];
  var myResult = parseFloat(myBox1) * parseFloat(myBox2);
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="qid1" data-quantity name="qamount" min="0" data-validation="number" class="qinput txt" value="{{Quantity}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max100" class="dinput" value="{{Details}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="uid1" data-unitprice name="uamount" min="0" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" class="uinput txt" value="{{UnitPrice}}" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="subsubtotal" name="totalamount" class="sinput txt" value="{{Subtotal}}" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="qid2" data-quantity name="qamount" min="0" data-validation="number" class="qinput txt" value="{{Quantity}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max100" class="dinput" value="{{Details}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="uid2" data-unitprice name="uamount" min="0" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" class="uinput txt" value="{{UnitPrice}}" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="subsubtotal" name="totalamount" class="sinput txt" value="{{Subtotal}}" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, what i'm wanting it doing is multiply in all boxes, only the top row is multiplying the inputs, however every row that gets added after the first one, it stops calculating the inputs, new to Javascript as you can probably tell

Comment: @JacobHarrison : It's becuase of the `id` attribute. `id` should be unique in your whole document. So the input boxes in the second row should have a different `id`.

Comment: The 'add invoice button' on the image link I provided means there can be as many rows as the person wants, and that's done through javascript so I don't think it would be possible to add a unique ID to the other rows as there can be as many they like, so I'm after something that would target the boxes for all the inputs, however looking at my code I am not sure if It is written incorrectly for what I need. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works perfectly, all credit to you.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help :-)